# Change a Label text created dynamically in a layout in a ListBoxItem

Tags: android, delphi

I'm creating dynamically ListBoxItems in a ListBox. Inside the ListboxItem I'm creating Layouts (3 of them) and inside those, Labels. Now I'm trying to search and find a specific label and change its text. I know how to do it in a way without using layouts with controls, but to make them look nicer I use Layouts. (ListBoxItem parenting->Layout parenting->Label)
Check my code below that I use for searching the label and change the text.

```
  var e,h : integer;
      item : TListBoxItem;
      Ctrl:   TControl;
      Lbl :  TLabel absolute Ctrl;
      layout : TLayout absolute Ctrl;
  begin
  item := ListBox1.ListItems[itemNum]; // specific listboxitem
   for h:=0 to item.ControlsCount-1 do
     begin
      Ctrl:=item.Controls[h];
        if Ctrl is TLayout then
          begin
           if layout.Name='lout3' then  // i found the layout named "lout3" that i have 4 labels in
            begin
             for e:=0 to layout.ControlsCount-1 do  // i check that the control count is correct(4)
               begin
                Ctrl:=layout.Controls[e];   // but at this line error occur "Argument out of range"
                if Ctrl is TLabel then
                   begin
                     if Lbl.Name='qty1' then
                      begin
                      if ed_pos1.Text='' then
                       begin
                       Lbl.Text:=ed_pos1.TextPrompt;
                       end
                      else
                       begin
                       Lbl.Text:= ed_pos1.Text;
                       end;
                      end;
                     if Lbl.Name='qty2' then
                      begin
                      if ed_pos2.Text='' then
                       begin
                       Lbl.Text:=ed_pos2.TextPrompt;
                       end
                      else
                       begin
                       Lbl.Text:= ed_pos2.Text;
                       end;
                      end;
                     if Lbl.Name='qty3' then
                      begin
                      if ed_pos3.Text='' then
                       begin
                       Lbl.Text:=ed_pos3.TextPrompt;
                       end
                      else
                       begin
                       Lbl.Text:= ed_pos3.Text;
                       end;
                      end;
                   end;
                 end;
               end;
             end;
           end;
          end;
```

Somehow in that line layout.Controls don't have 4 entries that the controlCount says before. It goes in the loop for e=0 and the second time that enter the loop, e=1, it crashes with that error message.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are using absolute keyword which makes it really easy to shoot yourself in the foot. Even more so, when you have two variables (`layout` and `Lbl`) pointing to one (`Ctrl`).

The problem in your code is that you set `Ctrl` to a layout in the first loop, and then in the second loop you are reusing that variable again and assigning `Ctrl:=layout.Controls[e]` which basically translates to `Ctrl:=Ctrl.Controls[e]` because of the `absolute` directive and your layout variable no longer holds the actual layout control in the second loop iteration.

You should use separate variable for second loop. I would suggest that you don't use absolute and simply directly use appropriate variable with typecasting.

You can even avoid typecasting, depending on properties you use. For instance `layout` can easily be declared as `TControl` and you just need to check its type to be sure you are accessing the layout, but you don't have to type cast it.

```
  var e,h : integer;
      item : TListBoxItem;
      layout : TControl;
      Lbl :  TLabel;
  begin
  item := ListBox1.ListItems[itemNum]; 
   for h:=0 to item.ControlsCount-1 do
     begin
       layout := item.Controls[h]; 
       if layout is TLayout then
         begin
           if layout.Name='lout3' then  
            begin
             for e:=0 to layout.ControlsCount-1 do  
               begin
                if layout.Controls[e] is TLabel then
                   begin
                     Lbl := TLabel(layout.Controls[e]);
                   ...
```